# How to plot orbit of binary star and calculate its orbital elements?

Tags: python, numerical-analysis

I have a set of dates, position angles ($\theta$) and angular separations ($\rho$) for visual binary star. For example:

```
1994.3132  57.0    0.097
1996.1783  73.4    0.051
2006.1938 182.0    0.126
2009.2597 192.9    0.152
etc.
```

What are algorithms to calculate orbital elements and to plot the orbit of the binary star?

Are there available codes (or programs) for this calculations? Python is preferable )

Comment: Where have you already looked for methods and codes?

Comment: I looked here: http://adsabs.harvard.edu/abstract_service.html

Comment: Well, what have you found?

Comment: I have found only this: http://adsabs.harvard.edu/abs/1989AJ.....98.1014H

Answer (score 2):

If you google "calculate orbital elements binary star" you find these two as the first hits:

- http://ugastro.berkeley.edu/infrared10/adaptiveoptics/binary_orbit.pdf
- http://www.professores.uff.br/diomar_cesar_lobao/material/Astro-Dio/SABP94-CERCA.pdf

I am sure the following hits would also be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

The good software for orbit calculation is "Binary" (Binary Star Combined Solution Package) by CHARA team:

http://www.chara.gsu.edu/~gudehus/binary.html